# Sticky jquery-ui dialog does not let mouse pointer go

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It seems like  Jquery dialog is in love with my mouse pointer.

I have a jqgrid and a few text boxes inside a div which i am using as a dialog.

Whenever i try to move the dialog by dragging, it sticks to the mouse pointer and does not let  it go.

here is the code

```
$("#Applon").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 370,
    width: 710,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        //'Create an account': function() { },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            //$('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
});
```

how do i  get around this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Also when i open the dialogue, scrollbars appear on my page. when i open the dialog for the second time scrollbars appear on the dialog too.

**EDIT 2**

here is the grid

```
jQuery('#jgrid2').jqGrid({
    autowidth: true,
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'grdAltRwClr',
    datatype: 'local',
    forceFit: true,
    gridview: true,
    mtype: 'post',
    height: 190,
    //width: 350,
    rowNum: 0,
    postData: { p_hdrid: function() { return $('#p_hdrid').val(); } },
    url: window.rootPath + 'Invoice/JGridDtlData',
    beforeSelectRow: function() { return false; },
    gridComplete: function() {
        GridComplete2();
    },
    colModel: [
        { name: 'act', label: 'View', resizable: false, search: false, sortable: false, title: false, width: 8, index: 'act' }
        , { name: 'p_slabid', label: 'Slab ID', width: 15, index: 'p_slabid' }
        , { name: 'p_fslab', label: 'From', width: 15, index: 'p_fslab', sortable: false }
        , { name: 'p_tslab', label: 'Upto', width: 15, index: 'p_tslab', sortable: false }
        , { name: 'p_amt', label: 'Amount', width: 15, index: 'p_amt', sortable: false }

         ]
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="Applon" title="Edit Slab Details" style="border-style: 1px; width: 680px; height:370px; background-color: #00CC99; z-index: 999; display: block; padding-left: 10px;">
    <div class="content">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <form action="\" id="frmDtl">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                       ....controls go here

                    </table>
                </form>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="content" style="width: 690px">
        <table id="jgrid2">
        </table>
        <div id="pager2">
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

**Edit**:3 Here is the CSS

```
element.style {
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
jquery...s?v=5.3 (line 12)
.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    cursor: move;
}
jquery...s?v=5.3 (line 417)
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
jquery...s?v=5.3 (line 391)
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background-color: #5D81AB;
    background-image: url("../../Images/ThkStrip.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
Sales_...s?v=5.3 (line 1436)
.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
jquery...s?v=5.3 (line 282)
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #C4D1E7;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
}
jquery...s?v=5.3 (line 55)
.ui-helper-clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You should add your html and css as well.

Comment: thanks but its huge page with two grids , 2 tabs and three modal forms.

Comment: You can add just the dialog div and the pertinent css.

Comment: In fact can you create a fiddle with your data then we can look at your fiddle, then it won't pollute the real estate on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) using the code you supplied.

http://jsfiddle.net/6FWPc/

This works in both chrome and IE...

Can you confirm it works for you too?

**EDIT**
As Monkieboy says the mouse up event is happening outside of the browser so until you click again the dialog thinks you are still in the mouse down event.

All I can think of is making draggable false:

```
$("#Applon").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 370,
    width: 710,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        //'Create an account': function() { },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            //$('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/cumsL/

**EDIT 2**
You can use the mouseleave() event to register the mouseup() see fiddle

```
$('document').ready(function() {
     $("#main").mouseleave(function()
                           {
                               $(this).mouseup();
                           });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5D6J/

Comment: Yeah all my dialogs work fine Except this one. And this one has a Grid inside.

Comment: Can you supply the HTML/css for me and I'll update the fiddle?

Comment: my page is very big with 2 grids, 2 tabs and three modal forms

Comment: Sorry (still works http://jsfiddle.net/XtxZN/) what would be better is if you save the page from the browser. This way you'll get the contents too. I.e. spin it up in debug.. get the error to occur then (in chrome) control + S. Then the html and css should be available to be posted.

Comment: I just checked the problem is restricted to Firefox only. it renders fine in chrome and ie8. I am using jquery ui css.

Comment: I have managed to reproduce in Chrome, using jsfiddle.

Basically, I attempted to drag the dialog off the screen, but it ends up snapping to the edge of the frame, at which point I let go of the mouse button and when I re-enter the mouse cursor into the frame, the dialog follows the cursor.

Comment: Exactly . That is what happening but in my case it is not chrome but firefox.

Comment: and it happens without the grid too. So grid is not causing any conflict that is for sure.

Comment: Thats probably the best solution actually, to make `draggable` false

Comment: See edit.. making draggable false is the only workaround I can think of. http://jsfiddle.net/cumsL/

Comment: I think the problem is that the control loses context with the cursor when the cursor leaves the controls parent and when the mouse button is release the dialog does not register the mouse button being released, so when the cursor re-enters the parent, the dialog 'sees' the cursors and follows it as if the mouse button has not been released.

Unfortunately, I cannot say why it would illicit this behaviour I am sure enough Googling would unveil the reason.

Comment: yeah thats what i am going to do untill i find a solution. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @Monkieboy thanks if you come across something plz post a link seems like i am stuck with this for a long time

Comment: Sorry . In my case it only made it worse.

Comment: Oh dear.. then I think without a fiddle that can reproduce the problem.. we are I guess stuck.. you can confirm that http://jsfiddle.net/s5D6J/ doesn't help.. and that you update the $("#main") to be the id of the body of your page?

Answer (score 1):

To extend from Craftyfellas answer.....

```
$('document').ready(function() {
     $("#main").mouseleave(function()
                           {
                               $(this).mouseup();
                           });
});
```

Which is cool actually, you could actually bind it with the `live()` function so that all other dialogs also capture this behaviour. Like so:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#main").live("mouseleave", function() {
       $(this).mouseup();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could extend the `dialog`, so that it accounts for the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: thanks, my document was within I frame and now this solves it completely